# corrupted data AES C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, encryption, aes

Quick heads up, i know this is a duplicate but the answers did not help me.

So im trying to make an AES and RSA encrypted connection, so i can encrypt very large stuff, However upon decrypting something with AES, I`m met with garbage in the beginning of the data, Here is my code (yes i tried hardcoding the IV):

```cs
                RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
                rsa.KeySize = 1024;
                Aes aes = Aes.Create();
                aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567890123456");
                byte[] sendBytes = null;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
                client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 900));
                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
                ns.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rsa.ToXmlString(false) + "$"), 0, (rsa.ToXmlString(false) + "$").Length);
                ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                MessageBox.Show(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
                rsa.FromXmlString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Split('$')[0]);
                ns.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(aes.Key, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1)) + "$"), 0, (Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(aes.Key, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1)) + "$").Length);
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(aes.Key, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1)));
                ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor();
                sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("*" + Convert.ToBase64String(encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authResult.AccessToken), 0, authResult.AccessToken.Length)) + "|" + Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV) + "$");
                ns.Write(sendBytes, 0, ("*" + Convert.ToBase64String(encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authResult.AccessToken), 0, authResult.AccessToken.Length)) + "|" + Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV) + "$").Length);
                sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authResult.Account.Username), 0, authResult.Account.Username.Length)) + "$");
                ns.Write(sendBytes, 0, (Convert.ToBase64String(encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authResult.Account.Username), 0, authResult.Account.Username.Length)) + "$").Length);
                ns.Dispose();
                client.Close();
```

This is the server:

```cs
                    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom);
                    string dataFromClient = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom).Split("$")[0];
                    networkStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rsa.ToXmlString(false) + "$"));
                    rsa.FromXmlString(dataFromClient.Split("$")[0]);
                    int waste;
                    rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(key, out waste);
                    Console.WriteLine(rsa.KeySize.ToString());
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom);
                    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom));
                    aes.Key = rsa.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom).Split("$")[0]), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
                    ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor();
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom);
                    aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567890123456");
                    dataFromClient = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom).Split("|")[0].Split("*")[1]), 0, Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom).Split("|")[0].Split("*")[1]).Length));
                    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom).Split("|")[0].Split("*")[1]), 0, Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom).Split("|")[0].Split("*")[1]).Length)));
                    string info = await GetHttpContentWithToken("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", dataFromClient);
                    Console.WriteLine(info);
                    Root a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(info);
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom);
                    dataFromClient = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom).Split("$")[0]), 0, Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom).Split("$")[0]).Length));
```

(yes im messing with microsoft accounts, you can just ignore everything except for the key exchange and AES decryption code.)

Comment: There's an rsa encrypt limit, 256 bytes.

Comment: Are you two related?

Comment: Read the documentation for `NetworkStream.Read()` carefully, it seems you are not using it correctly. *This method reads data into buffer and returns the number of bytes successfully read. The Read operation reads as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter.* You aren't even saving the return value of the Read, and you have no way to loop until you receive all the data you need to complete the subsequent steps.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk You were probably right about something, it is not the wrong length, but it is not the same data that we wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a closer look, i realized i created the decryptor before the IV, sorry about that.